# Algorithm for Steiner points?

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry, discrete-mathematics, triangulation

I am trying to find resources that explain an easy to implement (not necessarily optimal but reasonable runtime) algorithm for inserting Steiner points in a triangulation.

There seems to be little literature on the topic. My understanding is that different people  pick different criteria to optimize, some pick triangle area, others total number of points...

The one I care about is maximizing the smallest angle, or said otherwise, making triangles approach equilateral sides.

I did find [this writeup](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebhudson/manuscripts/hudson07what.pdf), but it is too high level. I could try reading the original papers but I was wondering if there is a less formal and more intuition based explanation of the topic that I have not found.

Comment: Did you dig the bibliography ?

Comment: This thesis might help. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/delaunay-refinement.pdf

Comment: At a first glance, [this](https://iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/fleischmann/node54.html) seems to be a great source including more references.